# Servicemonitor with multiple targets

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter, servicemonitor

I have kube-prometheus-stack running on a kubernetes cluster along with prometheus-blackbox-exporter. I want to monitor multiple http targets. I have tried setting this up with an servicemonitor but when I add a target the target does not get the right labels

The servicemonitor yaml:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: blackbox
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: blackbox
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.20.0
    helm.sh/chart: prometheus-blackbox-exporter-5.7.0
    release: kube-prometheus
  name: blackbox-prometheus-blackbox-exporter
  namespace: default
spec:
  endpoints:
    - interval: 10s
      path: /probe
      port: http
      scheme: http
      params:
        module: 
        - http_2xx
        target:
          - https://google.com
          - https://example.com
      metricRelabelings:
      - sourceLabels: [__address__]
        targetLabel: __param_target
  jobLabel: kube-prometheus
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: blackbox
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-blackbox-exporter
```

But in grafana I only get one instance label right:
[grafana instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSQxH.png)

Answer (score 1):

spec.endpoints  is a [list](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md#monitoring.coreos.com/v1.ServiceMonitor). In yaml each lists element are defined with a [dash](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html).
So you have to modify your service monitor yaml as:

```yaml
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 10s
    path: /probe
    port: metrics
    params:
      module:
      - http_2xx
      target:
      - https://www.google.com
    relabelings:
      - sourceLabels: [__param_target]
        targetLabel: target

  - interval: 10s
    path: /probe
    port: metrics
    params:
      module:
      - http_2xx
      target:
      - https://www.example.com
    relabelings:
      - sourceLabels: [__param_target]
        targetLabel: target
```

It works
[like it is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMxzP.png)

Comment: This is not very DRY?!? Is it possible to do this without repeating all properties? like a `defaults` field maybe?